# How to reset defaultValue in input in Reacjs

Tags: reactjs

Here's my code:

```
editForm = (p, value, placeholder, name ) => {
      if (this.state.isEditing && p.id === this.state.idEditing){
         return (
            <form>
               <input type="text" name={name} className = {"form-control " + ((placeholder !== "Id") ? "editForm":"editId" ) } placeholder={placeholder} defaultValue={(placeholder === "Tên") ? p.name:value} onChange = {(event) => this.realtimeUser(event)}></input>
               <button type="reset" className="btn btn-success"  value="Reset" onClick = {(event) => this.resetDefaultValue(event)}>Reset</button>
            </form>)
      }else return value;
   }
```

Here's my interface:
[image]

I don't know what should I write in `resetDefaultValue(event)` or is there any way to reset defaultValue = [1, Pacific Rim, 0969278743] in  `input` tags. Or is there another way to reset it? Thanks

Comment: maintain a react state for default values and when button reset is click set your default states to inputs fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should have **value** attribute on your input and control it with react state.
see documentation https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components

Then this.resetDefaultValue(event) function can setState of the value to be whatever you like.